# Can not install jekyll and its Runtime Dependencies

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, opensuse

I'm not a programmer but love to work with jekyll and markdown.

I've installed and used jekyll on many Linux distros (mostly debian flavours though).

Now I'm on Opensuse 13.1 which is a wonderfull solid Linux Distro.

Anyways, 
My problem is that I simply can not install jekyll and its Runtime Dependencies.
I've tried all possible solutions (I think) and now I'm lost.

This is the output when trying to install `classifier`.

```
>> sudo gem install classifier  
sudo gem install classifier
root's password:
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'classifier' (>= 0), here is why:  
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org - no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)  

ERROR:  Possible alternatives: classifier
```

**Any advise ??**

I've installed all the devel libraries with:

```
>> sudo zypper in -t pattern devel_basis
```

And updated the ruby-gems with:

```
>> sudo gem update --system --source http://rubygems.org  

>> gem -v
2.2.2
```

Below some info that could be usefull for troubleshooting:

```
>> ruby -v  
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
```

> ruby-devel 2.0-5.1.2

```
>> gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby2.0
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/niels/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.0.0
     - /home/niels/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :benchmark => false
     - "install" => "--format-executable --no-user-install"
     - "format_executable" => true
     - "update" => "--format-executable --no-user-install"
     - :sources => nil
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/niels/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/bin/X11
     - /usr/X11R6/bin
     - /usr/games
```

Comment: What happens when you enter `gem install jekyll`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did get it sorted out.

The solution for me was to write this in a terminal
    `sudo update_rubygems`

And then
`sudo gem install jekyll`

Now it works :-)